# Nested colorboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a web site in which the end user can click a button to open a form to be filled out.  Within that form, another button can be clicked to open another form to provide additional information.  The code is as follows:

To open the main form:

```
<script src="/Scripts/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#NewGameButton").click(function () {
            $.colorbox({ width: "80%", height: "80%", iframe: true, href: "/utility/NewGame.aspx" });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Within NewGame.aspx:

```
<script src="/Scripts/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("NewGameType").click(function () {
            $.colorbox({ width: "80%", height: "80%", iframe: true, href: "/utility/NewGameType.aspx" });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The main form (NewGame.aspx) opens without any issue, but when I click the button to open NewGameType.aspx, the iFrame flashes and then disappears.  There are no errors in the developer tools console in Chrome, so I don't have any idea what's going on.  Can anyone tell me how to make this work correctly?

Comment: Context: [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) is a lightbox plugin for jQuery

Comment: Typo? `$("NewGameType")` should be `$("#NewGameType")`?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, but didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is cause by simple click method. You need delegate click to new elements on page so:

### Main form:

```
<script src="/Scripts/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#NewGameButton").click(function () {
            $.colorbox({ width: "80%", height: "80%", iframe: true, href: "/utility/NewGame.aspx" });
        });


        $("NewGameType").on('click', function () {
            $.colorbox({ width: "80%", height: "80%", iframe: true, href: "/utility/NewGameType.aspx" });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In old jQuery versions you can do it by use `live`:

```
$("NewGameType").live('click', function () {..}
```

Here you can read more about `on` method and delegation [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: When changing the code to use .on(), I get the exact same result.  However, I am getting an error in the console.  It might not have anything to do with this:

Uncaught TypeError:  Object #<CSSStyleDeclaration> has no method 'removeAttribute' in jquery.colorbox.js line 730.

Comment: try don't use colorbox again and move your code to first document.

Comment: That didn't seem to make any difference either.

Answer (score 0):

I added class="NewGameButton" and class="NewGameType" to the respective buttons, then changed the code to:

```
        $(".NewGameButton").colorbox({ width: "80%", height: "80%", iframe: true, href: "/utility/NewGame.aspx" });

        $(".NewGameType").colorbox({ width: "80%", height: "80%", iframe: true, href: "/utility/NewGameType.aspx" });
```

That allows everything to work exactly as I wanted.